# С# Best Practice решение для использования нескольких BackgroundService объектов одного класса

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, backgroundworker

Я создал воркера, на базе `BackgroundService`. Внутри он коннектится к устройству и начинает `while(cancaletionToken)` цикл. Он работает, но вот мне теперь нужно создать таких несколько штук и при этом чтобы у каждого был свой `IConfiguration` или хотя бы свой property ip-адресса.

Есть ли какое-то build-in или best practice решение проблемы? Я, примерно, понимаю как делать это без `HostBuilder`-а, но интересно решение именно с ним. Я читал документацию MS и читал про Queue Service и scoped services, вроде это не то что нужно, либо я не понял их сути. Заранее спасибо

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Service>();
            });
}
```

**UPDATE:** заранее я не знаю сколько потребуется устройств – их количество должно определяться в `appsettings.json`. Сейчас я вызываю `ExecuteAsync` сервиса в `ExecuteAsync` другого сервиса, столько сколько необходимо, но не уверен, что это правильное решение.

Answer (score 1):

вижу 2 варианта:

1. в конфигурации (скорее всего apsetting.json) добавить коллекцию настроек для каждого устройства и потом в каждом Hosted сервисе брать нужный тебе.
2. в хостед сервисе генерировать свою конфигурацию по названию .json файла по его названию

```
    public IConfigurationRoot GetCameraConfiguration(string fileName)
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(fileName, true)
            .Build();
    }
```

и у результата этого метода можешь вызывать, например "GetSection()"

3. запускай несколько тасков с разными параметрами. внутри своего хостед сервиса

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Забыл уточнить, что заранее не знаю сколько потребуется устройств – их количество должно определяться в appsettings.json. 3-ий вариант я использую сейчас, но не знаю правильный ли это подход, поэтому и спросил про best practice